# Deploying a shell script inside Docker on Ubuntu for ECS results in 'exec /pstart.sh: no such file or directory' error. How do I fix this?

Tags: docker, shell, ubuntu, amazon-ecs

I want to run shell script inside docker and deploy it to ECS but I am getting below error

> exec /pstart.sh: no such file or directory

Please find below docker file and sh file contents

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/ubuntu/ubuntu:latest

RUN apt-get update && \
    DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive \
    apt install -yq \
    curl \
    jq \
    openssh-server \
    unzip \
    vim \
    dnsutils \
    iputils-ping \
    iputils-tracepath

RUN curl "https://awscli.amazonaws.com/awscli-exe-linux-x86_64.zip" -o "awscliv2.zip" && \
    unzip awscliv2.zip && \
    rm -f awscliv2.zip && \
    ./aws/install

ADD pstart.sh /
RUN chmod +x /pstart.sh

RUN echo PasswordAuthentication no >> /etc/ssh/sshd_config
RUN echo Port 2224 >> /etc/ssh/sshd_config

CMD ["/pstart.sh"]
```

pstart.sh as below

```
#!/bin/sh

ssh-keygen -q -t rsa -N '' -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa <<<y >/dev/null 2>&1
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub > ~/.ssh/authorized_keys

KEY_ID=$(aws kms list-aliases | jq -r '.Aliases | .[] | select(.AliasName=="alias/prod-smos-kms-key") | .TargetKeyId')

aws ssm put-parameter --name smos-ssh-tunnel --value "$(cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa)" --type "SecureString" --overwrite --key-id "${KEY_ID}"

service ssh start

while (true); do
  sleep 5000
done
```

In below image you can see pstart.sh file is present.
[image]

Error

[image]

I tried changing EOL  chartacter from CRLF to LF as suggested in other solutions.

I tried changing #!/bin/bash to #!/bin/sh

I tried using ENTRYPOINT instead of CMD.

I tried COPY pstart.sh / instead of ADD pstart.sh /

Comment: Can you run the same docker image locally without issues?

Answer (score 0):

If I build an image from your Dockerfile and `pstart.sh` script and run it locally, I get:

```
/pstart.sh: 3: Syntax error: redirection unexpected
```

And that's because you're attempting to use Bash-specific syntax in `pstart.sh` (in particular the `<<<` redirection operator), but in your image `/bin/sh` isn't Bash.

You can fix this by replacing the "shebang" line in your script with:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

With this change, the container boots without errors.

You could also rewrite `pstart.sh` using legacy Bourne shell syntax.

---

I cannot reproduce the "no such file or directory" error that you report.